# Constraints for indexed addressing

Tags: gcc, assembly, 68hc11

(This is a followup from ["Getting GCC to optimize hand assembly"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18775544/20862))

I've been trying to get GCC (3.3.6-m68hc1x-20060122) to emit `bset` and `bclr` assembly instructions using indexed addressing, but no set of constraints I use seems to work.

The `asm`:

```
#define bset(base, offset, mask) { \
volatile unsigned char *__base = base; \
const unsigned char __offset = offset; \
const char __mask = mask; \
asm volatile ("bset %0 %1" : "=o" (__base[__offset]) : "X" (__mask),
  "x" (__base)); }
```

The C:

```
inline void spi_init()
{
  bset(_io_ports, M6811_DDRD, 0x38);
  bset(_io_ports, M6811_PORTD, 0x20);
  bset(_io_ports, M6811_SPCR, (M6811_SPE | M6811_DWOM | M6811_MSTR));
}
```

The assembly code result:

```
spi_init:
        ldx     #_io_ports
; Begin inline assembler code
#APP
        bset _io_ports+9 #56
        bset _io_ports+8 #32
        bset _io_ports+40 #112
; End of inline assembler code
#NO_APP
        rts
```

Now this is *really, really* close. But unfortunately it's **completely invalid**. It must read as follows:

```
spi_init:
        ldx     #_io_ports
; Begin inline assembler code
#APP
        bset 9,x #56
        bset 8,x #32
        bset 40,x #112
; End of inline assembler code
#NO_APP
        rts
```

What constraints must I use in order to direct GCC to emit that assembly code?

[GCC 3.3.6 extended assembly documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm)
[GCC 3.3.6 constraint documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Constraints.html#Constraints)

Comment: Just wondering; shouldn't there be a comma between `%0` and `%1` in your `asm` statement?

Comment: @Michael: Possibly. Depends on what the assembler (gas 2.23.52 in this case) takes. But that's the easy part.